# Mongoose - Whole object select false

Tags: node.js, mongoose, orm, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose-model declaration which contain a object with a bunch of individual fields. I don't want each field to be returned by default and so set the "select: false" property for each individual field in the object of my mongoose-model.

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    location: {
        city: { type: String, select: false },
        country: { type: String, select: false },
        postcode: { type: String, select: false },
        street: { type: String, select: false }
    }
})
```

Instead of having the `.select`-property for each property of my location-obj, I want to set the "select: false" for the whole location-object and so either receive the entire nested object when using `.select("+location")` or none of the properties by default instead of having it like yet where i need to select each field individually like `.select("+location.city +location.country +location.postcode")`